# getting null in an @Autowired field in Abstract class

Tags: spring, components, autowired

I have a abstract class, and inherited by several subclasses.  In another class i get the class name and need to instantiate the class to call a base method in the parent(abstract) class. But i got null in an @Autowired field 'cache' which used in the base method. The className is an input field from the front end. So i think i have to do instantiate a new object in order to call the method. Thanks in advance!

```
public abstract class Data(){
   @Autowired protected Cache cache;

   private Abc getDataContent(){
      if(cache.containsKey()){
        //do something
      }else{
        //do something else
      }
    }    
}

public class Data1 extends Data(){
  public Data1(){
    super();
  }
}

public class Data2 extends Data(){
  public Data2(){
    super();
  }
}


public class Resource(){

  public Abc getContent(){
    Class<Data<?>> className = getClassName();
    //className  will be the classCanonicalName of Data1 or Data2;

    return className.newInstance().getDataContent();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the null field, you need to let spring manage the beans (objects), and a simple way to do it is to use `@Component` annotation on `Data1` and `Data2`.

Also, please note that if you manually instantiate an object (e.g. `new Data1();` ) then Spring will be unaware of that instance;

Comment: I tried to add a @Component to both Data1 and Data2, but the cache is still null. I know the issue is the new object instantiated, but is there a way to do it? Since I have to instantiate the object to call the base method in the superclass in order to identify generate key for the cache.

Comment: You dont have to instantiate the objects, you can just inject them; instead of using `new Data1();`, create a new field `private Data1 data1;` annotated with `@Autowired`;

Comment: the issue is the class name is an input field from the front end, i can't autowired an object without knowing what it is in the back.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `@Autowire`, your object should be in the spring `ApplicationContext` or the IOC container, you can't directly make an instance of it via reflection beacasue spring is using CGlib proxy to enhance your classes and make it available via application context to inject into your  implementation. [Spring Beans and Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

Comment: do you know i can put my newly instantiated obj in the spring ApplicationContext or IOC?